# Setting relative path for PDF linking to shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-3, pdf, file-path

I am trying to link a PDF for a shapefile, but I'm unable to set a relative path. How can I set a relative path in QGIS? I am only able to open the PDF in my PC, whereas when share this file to others, they are able to open the file only when they change the path in the attributes. Note: The attcachment and shapefile are in two different subfolders. The path for shapefile is "F:\GIS\SHP\POZZETTI_.shx" whereas path for PDF is  "F:\GIS\PDF\PDF_POZZETTI\POZZETTO_1.pdf"

[image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a1Su.png)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. "I tried a lot of things" isn't very descriptive. Your goal here is to write not only a question that can be answered, but a Question that can be found by others with the same problem.

Comment: A shapefile is a set of three files with the same 8.3 prefix ending in `.shp`, `.shx`, and `.dbf` (plus other optional files with the same prefix). The correct way to reference it is by the `.shp`.

Answer (score 4):

#### Solution

Using QGIS expression with function [`file_path()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#file-path) and variable [`@layer`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#variables), you get the path of the current layer: `file_path (@layer)`. Using this, the file you want to access must be stored in the same folder as the layer.

Concatenate this with the filename to get what you want, using function [`concatenate()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#concatenate) or even easier using [pipes `||`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#expression-function-operators-concat) as operator to concatenate: `file_path (@layer) || '/filename.pdf'`

Be sure to avoid paths containing special characters or spaces and be sure that the the filename stored in the Attribute called `Fieldname` comes with the extension `.pdf` at the end. Otherwise, add `'.pdf'` as a string at the end of the expression:

`file_path (@layer) || '/' || "Fieldname" || '.pdf'`

---

#### Example

So if you have an attribute field called `file` where you store the filename (e.g. `my_file.pdf`), use this expression to create the raltive path to this file:

```
file_path (@layer) || '/'  || "file"
```

Depending on Operation System, you might have to replace backslashes `\` with forward slashes `/`. To do so, use this expression (be aware that in QGIS, backslahes are double masked `\\`):

```
replace (
    file_path (@layer) || '/'  || "file",
    '\\',
    '/'
)
```

*Screenshot: the expression creates the path to the folder where the layer is saved and looks for a file named like the value stored in the attribute field `"file"`:*
[image]

Comment: Hello , Thank you your response, but it's not working for me , so i will give my project details. So that could you please write the exact condition which will be helpful for me. My Qgis project folder is D:\learn\qgis and the shapfile layer name is trail . Whereas my pdf is the same folder of the project as 1.pdf . So could you please write me the condition in my case that could set me a relative path. Thank you

Comment: It depends where exactly you want to have the path and for what? You want to create an attribute value as a text string?

Comment: Yes i created an attribute value as text and assigned action to it. So when send this project to my friend in his computer the pdf is not opening. Because of the path difference.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: F:\Akwa Dropbox\Lavori\02-F\2022-5 Consulenza Frana Petralia Sottana\2023_FOGNATURA_PETRALIA\GIS\PDF\PDF_POZZETTI\POZZETTO_1.pdf   only wirth this path i am able to open PDF on my computer not others. I tried the above  expression given by babel , but i dont know what the problem is it is not working.

Comment: Do you use Dropbox? Is it a remote folder? Did you try to replace \ by /?

Comment: Did you test on the other computers if you can open the file with the path outside of QGIS? Please provide more information about the Operating System and the kind of folder you want to access. There seem to be a lot of information missing to give an answer. Provide a path working to open the pdf on the other computers to see what is going wrong.

Comment: I am working on windows 10 pro. my qgis version is 3.22.13. I use drop box. I svaed my projecti in F:\Akwa Dropbox\Lavori\02-F\2022-5 Consulenza Frana Petralia_Sottana\2023_FOGNATURA_PETRALIA , whereas my layer path is F:\Akwa Dropbox\Lavori\02-F\2022-5 Consulenza Frana Petralia_Sottana\2023_FOGNATURA_PETRALIA\GIS\SHP\POZZETTI_.shp and my pdf saved in F:\Akwa Dropbox\Lavori\02-F\2022-5 ConsulenzaFranaPetralia_Sottana\2023_FOGNATURA_PETRALIA\GIS\PDF\PDF_POZZETTI\POZZETTO_1 .so in his system  drop box  is in :D instead of :F, so when we try to open we are not able to open it.

Comment: The attribute is in column with Rilievo. so  when tried with the expression you has provided , even on my system the pdf is not opening.[%file_path (@layer) || '/'  || "Rilievo"%]. I am only able to open the pdf with field used F:\Akwa Dropbox\Lavori\02-F\2022-5 Consulenza Frana Petralia_Sottana\2023_FOGNATURA_PETRALIA\GIS\PDF\PDF_POZZETTI\POZZETTO_1.pdf   I also tried with back slashes as you suggested in the previous example

Comment: Pleae don't use comments for clarifications of your questions. Edit your initial question and add the info there.

Comment: The path you provided contains spaces `2022-5 Consulenza Frana Petralia_Sottana`, but the pdf path has no spaces here: `2022-5 ConsulenzaFranaPetralia_Sottana`. Avoid spaces in folder/filne names! Also in your pdf path, the file extension `.pdf` is missing. Add this to the string.

Comment: If in attribute `Rilievo` you just have the string `POZZETTO_1`, the file will not open. You must have `POZZETTO_1.pdf` here! If not, add the extension at the end: `[%file_path (@layer) || '/' || "Rilievo" || '.pdf'%]`

Comment: The long file paths you use are a bit messy. Just for testing purpose to identify the problem try using a simple path like `F:/my_folder` that should become `D:/my_folder` on the other machine. If it doesn't work, please copy the value from the preview when you enter the expression. Otherwise, it's difficult to help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145081/discussion-between-venkata-ravikiran-and-babel).

Comment: Please add details to the initial question so that it can be reopened